# Why using this declare a global variable in functions?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have this code:

```
function boo() {
    this.is_global = "Yes!";
}
```

When I run the `boo();`, I have `is_global` in `window` object, I mean the `is_global` goes into global context.
I expected to have `is_global` in `boo` function only.

Is this a normal behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the window. If you want to refer to the function, use:

```
arguments.callee.is_global = "Yes!";
```

Now:

```
window.is_global; //undefined
boo.is_global; //"Yes!"
```

An alternative way would be to simply refer to boo by its own name when adding properties to it.

```
function boo() {
    boo.is_global = "Yes!";
}
```

Note that this modifies the original `boo` function object. If you wish to modify all *instances* of `boo` resulting from using it as a constructor instead, please see the other answers here.

Comment: You can't use `arguments.callee` is strict mode; it is best avoided.

Comment: So is there any difference between using `var is_global = "Yes";` and `boo.is_global = "Yes!";`?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani Yes there is. If you use `var is_global = "Yes";`, evaluating boo.is_global outside the function will return undefined. If you use the approach here, `boo.is_global` will return `"Yes!"`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is normal behaviour. If your function is defined globally, `this` is just `window` and anything added to `window` is global.

Answer (score 1):

To have `this` be "the function being called", you have to call the function as an object constructor (using `new`).

```
var foo = new boo();
```

This will create an *instance* of `boo` with the property `is_global`. This will not create a property on the constructor function itself. [See a demo](http://jsbin.com/usevik/1/edit).

If you don't use `new` (or a method such as `apply`), then `this` is "The object on which the function is called". Since there is no object in this case, the default object is used. In the context of a web browser, the default object is `window`. So:

```
var foo = boo();
```

is the same as

```
var foo = window.boo();
```

and `this` is `window` inside `boo`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MDN's introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

I guess you wanted to declare a local variable, so use a [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).